# How does one copy (duplicate) and move a file from the same folder as the AppleScript code?

Tags: file, copy, applescript, duplicates

Something along these lines?

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate file "somefile.txt" of folder of (file (path to me)) to folder applications of folder startup disk
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, but here is the correct script.

```
tell application "Finder" to duplicate "somefile.txt" of (container of (path to me)) to applications folder
```

---

```
tell application "Finder"
    set prevTIDs to Applescript's text item delimiters
    set Applescript's text item delimiters to ":"
    duplicate "somefile.txt" of (text items 1 thru -2 of (path to me as string)) as alias to applications folder
    set Applescript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks -- when I run that script it comes back with:                 Can’t get "somefile.txt" of (container of (path to me)). Access not allowed.

Comment: @Jayer It should work. I updated the post to show you another way to do it.